# Adding columns into sqlite3 table dynamically using list

Tags: python, sqlite, go-sqlite3

I have been trying to insert column list  into table but unable to do so here is what i want to do

Let say i have a list of column names `column=["Email","Name","Salary"]` and i want to insert these columns into a table without hardcoding them , using column list only what is the best and easy way of doing it , i have read multiple answers but unable to understand , as i am a beiginer please explain it in basic manner , in python
i have tried it using

```py
column=["Email","Name","Salary"] 
'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE(? TEXT NOT NULL,? TEXT NOT NULL,? TEXT NOT NULL)''',(column[0],column[1],column[2])
```

but i am getting the syntax error
Please help me i am beginner

Comment: You should remove coma (`,`) between `TEXT` and `NOT NULL` in your query.

Comment: I added comma by mistake in this ques , but on my machine i didnt use comma it was giving syntax error , now  i edited the ques and has removed comma Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use an f-string in python to create your sqlite instructions.
So, you could do:

```py
table_string = f"CREATE TABLE employee({column[0]} TEXT, {column[1]} TEXT, {column[2]} TEXT)"
cur.execute(table_string)
```

Comment: You can let `sqlite3` module to add parameters, just pass `column` as second parameter of [`execute()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).